# Missing R.java on Linux Eclipse Android project

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Indigo with Android SDK 4.0.3 and Google API in Linux 11.10. However, when I start up a new Android project, my R.java is no where to be found, hence resulting in the following issue:

```
package com.lol.asdf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AsdfActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I have tried all suggestion on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) but it's no good.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your R.java is an auto generated class from the res/ folder. Check for error inside it. Try clean and rebuild your project too.

Answer (score 0):

R.java will generated automatically... 
first **solve all other errors** of your project it will be created...

Comment: I start my project CLEAN (no code of my own) and this problem is still there.

Comment: So you're saying even if I start a project clean and add no code of my own it can still have errors?

Comment: ya but you have someone else code rite so find error first dear